# how to check if a UITableViewCell is not nil (is initialized) inside heightForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` that I need to resize as the user types. The cell has a `UITextView` as a subview.

Inside heightForRowAtIndexPath, I need to check whether the current cell is nil or initialized.

If it's nil, I calculate its height based on text in a string property.

If it's NOT nil (i.e. initialized), I want it to retrieve the text property of the cell's subview (I know I can access it if the cell is initialized).

**How can I check if a UITableViewCell is nil or not within `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`?** I tried

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([overviewTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] !=nil)
    {    NSLog(@"YEEHAW!");
    }
}
```

but it results in an error (probably because `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` expects the cell to be initialized, not nil). Also, I noticed that `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` calls `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` (resulting in a recursive loop).

I've seen many "alternatives" on the web, but I was just wondering whether this approach is would work (or is valid at all).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I actually found a simple alternative that works (using beginUpdates/endUpdates), but it seemed like a hack (it is undocumented) and I was wondering if this approach was valid.

Comment: To use the `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` pairing you still need a way to calculate the changed height for the row, which seems to me more your question? Am I wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could check if the `indexPath` for the cell of interest is visible or not:

```
if ([[overviewTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] containsObject:indexPath])
{
    //Do something here
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's actually a VERY clever idea! Thanks so much!